# Angular Material *matNoDataRow doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've made a MatTable where you can filter. If there is no data matching the filter, I want to show a text using the ***matNoDataRow** directive mentioned in the Angular Material documentation. However, it doesn't work as in the examples by Angular Material.
Is there something I forgot? Or is this directive not yet working?
I use Angular 9.

Here is my table:

```html
<mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill" >
    <mat-label >Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="filter this table" (click)="searching=true" #input >
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="input.value=''; doFilter(''); searching= !searching" color="accent">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!searching">search</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="searching">clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="sticky-container" style="margin-top: 2em;">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort matSortActive="EXPIRY DATE" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>CUSTOMER ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer; let i = index" class="no-outline" 
                routerLink="/summary/customer/{{customerService.id}}">{{customer.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="exDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>EXPIRY DATE</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer; let i = index" class="table-bold no-outline" 
                routerLink="/summary/customer/{{customerService.id}}">{{customer.exDate | date: "dd.MM.yyyy"}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="companyName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>COMPANY / PARTNER</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer; let i = index"  class="no-outline" 
                routerLink="/summary/customer/{{customerService.id}}">{{customer.companyName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="export">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer; let i = index">
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="export" (click)="export()">
                    <mat-icon color="primary">get_app</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true" ></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index" (mouseover)="customerService.getId([row.id])"></tr>
        
        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data.-->
        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30, 100, dataSource.data.length]" color="accent"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: is the correct directive CdkNoDataRow? I'm seeing that inside Angular material docs

Comment: It was right how I implemented it. The only reason why it didn't work was I had to update my Angular to version 10. See answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That feature is only available in the latest version of Angular (v10). If you switch the documentation to show v9 (right now it shows 9.2.4), you'll see that feature isn't part of the API.

That said, I can't get it to work either. Even in Angular 10. :(

UPDATE: I did get it to work. (I'm using Angular 10.0.1). My working code looks exactly how you've implemented it. So upgrading to Angular 10 should do the trick for you.

Comment: For anyone trying to make it work, there are 2 more points to consider:

1. Add `CdkColumnDef` to providers of the module, component of which is using this functionality. Otherwise you'll see `NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkColumnDef!`, even though `MatTableModule` is imported.

2. Use `<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>` instead of `<tr mat-row *matNoDataRow>`. Otherwise you won't see neither `<td>` with message, nor error.

Comment: does anyone know how to implement that feature with <mat-table></mat-table> not ordinary table

Comment: The best source of documentation (with examples for mat-table) for this feature that I've found are the unit tests in the github repo: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table.spec.ts

Comment: @Navruzbek Noraliev I don't think MatNoDataRow works with mat-row, because mat-row does not accept content. I had to use <tr class="mat-row"><td class="mat-cell"> and vertical align the cell.

Comment: When you use <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow> *matNoDataRow works. Have a look at my main question. The only problem there was I had to update Angular Material to Version 10.

Comment: I also ran into the issue that <mat-row> and <tr mat-row..> do not work with *matNoDataRow should there be a github issue for this? or can someone explain the difference between setting a css class vs directive

Comment: One more important thing. You should use `<td class="mat-cell">` instead of `<td mat-cell>`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Jesse. It works well in Angular 10. There is nothing wrong with your code. Even I did the same to check.

```
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data found</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `*matNoDataRow` to work, the `dataSource` object array has to be empty like so:

```js
// *matNoDataRow hidden
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data>;

// *matNoDataRow revealed
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Data>([]);

// or 
dataSource.data = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="mat-row no-data-row" *matNoDataRow>
  <td class="mat-cell">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
</tr>

in scss file:
tr.no-data-row{
  display: flex;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  td{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-height: inherit;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```